# $D=d+w$ acting on forms

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms

Acting one basis $e^a$, The covariant derivatives
\begin{align}
D e^a = de^a + w^{a}{}_{b} \wedge e^b
\end{align}
where $w^{a}{}_{b}$ is the one-form spin connection.

I am having difficulties for expressions of $D X_{ab}$ where $X_{ab}$ $0$-form, $1$-form and $2$-form.

My idea for $X_{ab}$ on two form is
\begin{align}
D X^{ab} = dX^{ab} + w^{a}{}_{c} \wedge X^{cb} - X^{a}{}_{c} \wedge w^{c}{}_{b} 
\end{align}
and acting on one-form is
\begin{align}
D X^{ab} = dX^{ab} + w^{a}{}_{c} \wedge X^{cb} + X^{a}{}_{c} \wedge w^{c}{}_{b} 
\end{align}
and finally acting on zero-form is
\begin{align}
D X^{ab} = dX^{ab} + w^{a}{}_{c}  X^{cb} - X^{a}{}_{c}  w^{c}{}_{b} 
\end{align}

### The followings are my reasoning

Recall Cartan's structure formula
\begin{align}
&T^a = De^a =de^a + w^a{}_{b} \wedge e^b \\
&R^{ab} = d w^{ab} + w^{a}{}_{c} \wedge w^{cb} 
\end{align}
If we employ covariant derivatives once more, we get $D R^{ab}=0$.

\begin{align}
D R^{ab} &= dR^{ab} + w^{a}{}_{c} \wedge R^{cb} - R^{a}{}_{c} \wedge w^{c}{}_{b} \\
& = (d w^{ac} \wedge w_{c}{}^{b} - w^{ac} \wedge d w_{c}{}^{b} ) + w^{a}{}_{c} \wedge ( dw^{cb} + w^{cd} \wedge w_{d}{}^{b}) - (dw^{ac} + w^{ad} \wedge w_{d}{}^{c} ) \wedge w_{cb} =0
\end{align}
That's the reason why for $2$-form $X_{ab}$, I obtain

\begin{align}
D X^{ab} = dX^{ab} + w^{a}{}_{c} \wedge X^{cb} - X^{a}{}_{c} \wedge w^{c}{}_{b} 
\end{align}

Second under the decomposition of spin-connection $w^{ab} = \mathring{w}^{ab} + \kappa^{ab}$ where $\mathring{w}$ is torsion-less part so that $de^a + \mathring{w}^{a}{}_{b} \wedge e^b=0$, and hence $T^a = \kappa^{a}{}_{b} \wedge e^b$.

In the literature, they just wrote the decomposition $R^{ab} = \mathring{R}^{ab} + \mathring{D} \kappa^{ab} + \kappa^{a}{}_{c} \wedge \kappa^{c}{}_{b}$. Here $\kappa_{ab}$ is one-form. Hence the direct computations gives
\begin{align}
 D^2 e^a &= R^{a}{}_{b} \wedge e^b = (d w^{a}{}_{b} + w^{a}{}_{c} \wedge w^{c}{}_{b} ) \wedge e^b  \\
   &= \left( \mathring{R}^{a}{}_{b} +  d \kappa^{a}{}_{b} + \mathring{w}^{a}{}_{c} \wedge \kappa^{c}{}_{b} + \kappa^{a}{}_{c} \wedge \mathring{w}^{c}{}_{b} + \kappa^{a}{}_{c} \wedge \kappa^{c}{}_{b} \right) \wedge e^b  \\
   & = \left( \mathring{R}^{a}{}_{b} + \mathring{D} \kappa^{a}{}_{b} + \kappa^{a}{}_{c} \wedge \kappa^{c}{}_{b} \right) \wedge e^b
\end{align}
So I guess for one-form $X_{ab}$
\begin{align}
D X^{ab} = dX^{ab} + w^{a}{}_{c} \wedge X^{cb} + X^{a}{}_{c} \wedge w^{c}{}_{b} 
\end{align}

---

Is my approach correct? then How one can extend this to arbitrary forms with an arbitrary index?

Comment: By the final boxed formula in my answer the middle sign and a lower index of $X$ do not make sense:  $$D X^{ab} = dX^{ab} + w^{a}{}_{c} \wedge X^{cb} \color{red}{-} X^{a}{}_{\color{red}{c}} \wedge w^{c}{}_{b}$$ (for your $2$-form). The other two formulas have similar problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attempt to make things compatible which one can read in various places
in the internet such as [this](http://teaching.hayehinrichsen.de/lecturenotes/gr.pdf) and
[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_connection#Cartan%27s_structure_equations).

- The spin connection ${\boldsymbol{\omega}^a}_b={{\boldsymbol{\omega}_\mu}^a}_b\,dx^\mu$ is a [$\mathfrak{so}(3,1)$-Lie-algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_group#Lie_algebra) valued one form. That is: for each general coordinate index $\mu$ (Greek letter), ${{\boldsymbol{\omega}_\mu}^a}_b$ is a  certain $(4\times 4)$-matrix in its Lorentz indices $a,b$ (Latin letters). Alternatively, one can view ${\boldsymbol{\omega}^a}_b$ as a $(4\times 4)$-matrix of ordinary one-forms.
- The indices of ${\boldsymbol{\omega}^a}_b$ are raised and lowered with the Lorentz metric $\eta={\rm diag}(1,1,1,-1)\,,$  $\boldsymbol{\omega}_{ab}=\eta_{ac}\,{\boldsymbol{\omega}^c}_b$, and not with the possibly curved metric $g_{\mu\nu}\,.$ Then there is anti-symmetry $\boldsymbol{\omega}_{ab}=-\boldsymbol{\omega}_{ba}\,.$
- The coordinate basis one forms $dx^\mu$ are related to basis one forms
  $\boldsymbol{e}^a$ in the local Lorentz frame by
  $\boldsymbol{e}^a={\boldsymbol{e}^a}_\mu\,dx^\mu\,.$ A vector field $\boldsymbol{X}$ can therefore have Lorentz components $X^a=\boldsymbol{e}^a(\boldsymbol{X})$ or
  ordinary coordinate components $X^\mu=dx^\mu(\boldsymbol{X})\,.$
  This vector field can be viewed as a vector-valued $0$-form. Its covariant derivative coming from the spin connection is therefore the Lorentz-vector valued one-form
  $$
  DX^a=dX^a+{\boldsymbol{\omega}^a}_b\,X^b\,.
  $$
  Applying this to the coordinate basis vector $\boldsymbol{e}_\mu$ gives
  $$
  D_\mu X^a=\partial_\mu X^a+{{\boldsymbol{\omega}_\mu}^a}_b\,X^b\,.
  $$
  Analogously, when $T^{ab}$ is a contravariant rank-$2$ tensor then
  \begin{align}
  D\, T^{ab}&=dT^{ab}+{\boldsymbol{\omega}^a}_c\,T^{cb}+
  {\boldsymbol{\omega}^b}_c\,T^{ac}\,,\\[2mm]
  D_\mu\, T^{ab}&=\partial_\mu T^{ab}+{{\boldsymbol{\omega}_\mu}^a}_c\,T^{cb}+
  {{\boldsymbol{\omega}_\mu}^b}_c\,T^{ac}\,.
  \end{align}
  The formulas are fully analogous to the Levi-Civita connection where
  the ordinary Christoffel symbols are replaced by ${{\boldsymbol{\omega}_\mu}^a}_b\,.$
- Now we go from $0$-forms to one-forms. If $\boldsymbol{\alpha}^a={\boldsymbol{\alpha}^a}_b\,\boldsymbol{e}^b$ is a Lorentz-vector valued one-form then the covariant derivative is defined as
  $$
  D\,\boldsymbol{\alpha}^a=d\boldsymbol{\alpha}^a+{\boldsymbol{\omega}^a}_b\color{red}{\wedge} \boldsymbol{\alpha}^b\,.
  $$
  Same rule, just that the product in $\mathbb R$ is replaced by the $\color{red}{wedge~product}$. When $\boldsymbol{\alpha}^{ab}$ is a rank-$2$ Lorentz-***tensor***-valued one-form then (fully compatible with the case for $T^{ab}$)
  $$
  D\,\boldsymbol{\alpha}^{ab}=d\boldsymbol{\alpha}^{ab}+{\boldsymbol{\omega}^a}_c\wedge\boldsymbol{\alpha}^{cb}\color{red}{+}
  {\boldsymbol{\omega}^b}_c\wedge\boldsymbol{\alpha}^{ac}\,.
  $$
  When $\boldsymbol{\alpha}$ has one contravariant upper and one covariant lower index the $\color{red}{+}$ sign becomes a minus sign, or which is the same, we can swap the factors in the
  wedge product and keep the plus sign:
  $$
  D\,{\boldsymbol{\alpha}^a}_b=d{\boldsymbol{\alpha}^a}_b+{\boldsymbol{\omega}^a}_c\wedge{\boldsymbol{\alpha}^c}_b+
  {\boldsymbol{\alpha}^a}_c\wedge {\boldsymbol{\omega}^c}_b\,.
  $$
- All of the above sign conventions are compatible with the formula in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_connection#Cartan%27s_structure_equations) by which the covariant derivative of a $(1,1)$-tensor valued $p$-form is
  $$\boxed{\quad\phantom{\Bigg|}
  D{V^a}_b=d{V^a}_b+{\boldsymbol{\omega}^a}_c\wedge {V^c}_b-(-1)^p\,{V^a}_c\wedge {\boldsymbol{\omega}^c}_b\,.\quad}
  $$
  When $V$ has two upper indices (like your $X$) we should have
  $$\boxed{\quad\phantom{\Bigg|}
  DV^{ab}=dV^{ab}+{\boldsymbol{\omega}^a}_c\wedge V^{cb}\color{red}{+}(-1)^p\,V^{ac}\wedge {\boldsymbol{\omega}^b}_c\,.\quad}
  $$
  Swapping the wedge products allows to get rid of the $(-1)^p\,:$
  $$\boxed{\quad\phantom{\Bigg|}
  D{V^a}_b=d{V^a}_b+{\boldsymbol{\omega}^a}_c\wedge {V^c}_b- {\boldsymbol{\omega}^c}_b\wedge {V^a}_c\,.\quad}
  $$
  $$\boxed{\quad\phantom{\Bigg|}
  DV^{ab}=dV^{ab}+{\boldsymbol{\omega}^a}_c\wedge V^{cb}\color{red}{+} {\boldsymbol{\omega}^b}_c\wedge\,V^{ac}\,.\quad}
  $$
  In that format the signs only depend on the index placements and not what rank $p$ that form $V$ has.